# bash script, get name of subdirectory

Tags: linux, bash

I am making a bash script to delete older timeshift snapshot, then create a new one, then update my system. I am stuck on how to pull the snapshot directory names from the timeshift directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
#We need to figure out which snap is older than the other without explicitly typing its name... 
#Below, the names are explicitly typed!

#snaps=/timeshift/snapshots

snap1=/timeshift/snapshots/2020-12-29_16-43-41
snap2=/timeshift/snapshots/2021-01-01_09-59-12

if [ $snap1 -ot $snap2 ]
then
  snap1=2020-12-29_16-43-41
  sudo timeshift --delete --snapshot $snap1

  if sudo timeshift --create --comments "Weekly update"; then
    sudo pacman -Syu
  else
    echo "Something didn't work"
  fi
fi
```

The snapshot names will not be static. How could I get this script to read the new name each time without me having to manually add it?

Comment: You want `snap1` and `snap2` to be the two most recent snapshot folders?

Comment: There will only ever be two, I'd like to make it so I don't have to manually insert their names each time

Comment: No, I'm still learning the basics of writing shell scripts. I'll give that a go, thanks.

Comment: So you want the most recent directory just?

Comment: @KamilCuk I just want to keep the most recent. I have gotten it to work using oguz ismail's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I went with after trying everything. I won't mark the other answer as I found the comment-answer (now deleted) more helpful. Thanks nonetheless.

```
#!/bin/bash 

snaps=(/timeshift/snapshots/*)

if [[ ${snaps[0]} -ot ${snaps[1]} ]]
then
  #$snaps becomes $snaps[0] here
  sudo rm -fr $snaps && echo "$snaps has been deleted."
  echo "Remaining snapshot:" && ls /timeshift/snapshots
  if sudo timeshift --create --comments "weekly update"
  then
    sudo pacman -Syu
  fi 
else
  echo "Something went wrong..."
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

If there will ever only be exactly two files in `/timeshift/snapshots` and they are both folders created by timeshift and their names cannot contain whitespace of any kind, then you can remove the oldest one with this:

```
rm -fr `ls -tr /timeshift/snapshots | head -1`
```

If there is only one instead of two, then you have to be a bit more creative with the following, which will remove the older of the head and the tail so long as they aren't the same name. I assume you don't want to accidentally remove the only remaining backup before the next backup is taken.

```
cd /timeshift/snapshots
snap1=`ls -tr | head -1`
snap2=`ls -tr | tail -1`
if [ "$snap1" != "$snap2" ]; then
   rm -fr "$snap1"
fi
```

The quotes allow for whitespace, if more robustness is required.

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to get your code to work. If I echo it, it results in the right directory being printed, however if I try to delete it, it states the directory does not exist.